# Получить свойство товара

Tags: битрикс

Доброго времени суток.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить свойство товара, точнее мне нужен бренд товара.

У меня есть id товара, я пытаюсь так:

```
$prop=CIBlockElement::GetByID($product['ID'])->GetNextElement()->GetProperties();
```

Но в этом случае он мне выдает все свойства, но мне из всех этих свойств нужно динамически получить свойство бренда, при этом не прописывая руками наименования поля, например если телефон то у него свойство бренда называется CELL_BRAND, у компов PC_BRAND и т.п. как мне получить динамически значение этих полей бренда имея только id товара?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одним запросом нет возможности

```
$IBLOCK_ID = 11;
$properties = CIBlockProperty::GetList(Array("sort"=>"asc", "name"=>"asc"), Array("ACTIVE"=>"Y","CODE"=>"%BRAND", "IBLOCK_ID"=>$IBLOCK_ID));
while ($prop_fields = $properties->GetNext())
{
  $idProperty[]=$prop_fields["ID"];
}
```

а потом

```
$productID = 12;
$iterator = CIBlockElement::GetPropertyValues($IBLOCK_ID, array("ID"=>$productID,'ACTIVE' => 'Y'), true, array('ID' => $idProperty));
while ($row = $iterator->Fetch())
{
  print_r($row);
}
```